# horizontal splitpane vue component not resizing in electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

dipping toe in water with Vue and Electron. I am attempting to use the splitpanes component from https://github.com/antoniandre/splitpanes but for some reason I am unable to get the panes to resize. I can see resized events firing, but nothing is reflected on-screen.

This should be fairly basic, but I am fairly new to Vue and electron, so would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. My gut is telling me this is something to do with CSS but with such a simple proof-of-concept failing I fear there is something fundamentally stuffed.

```
<template>
  <div id="app" style="color:dodgerblue;height:100%">
    <splitpanes horizontal class="default-theme">
      <pane>1</pane>
      <pane>2</pane>
      <pane>3</pane>
    </splitpanes>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import FileTable from '@/components/FileTable'
import { Splitpanes, Pane } from 'splitpanes'
import 'splitpanes/dist/splitpanes.css'
import '@/components/default.css'

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    // FileTable,
    Splitpanes,
    Pane
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  })
}
</script>
```

I note that with vertical split panes, the resizing can be done, just not with horizontal split panes.